# How to configure firebase hosting properly with React and Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-hosting

I have created a web app with express as a backend and react as the frontend. My problem is when I go to a page that doesn't exist, the API rewrite in my firebase.json takes over my whole react app. I get a **Cannot GET /pagethatdoesntxist** when I run the command firebase serve.

I just want my app to behave like a regular single page application. Do I have to change something in my firebase json config? Thank you

[image]

Here is my firebase.json hosting config

```
"hosting": {
        "public": "client/build",
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "**",
                "function": "api"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is my index file where I create the api routes and cloud functions

```
// * Routes
app.use("/user", userRoute);
app.use("/reports", reportsRoute);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```